# Difference between hypovolemic shock and heart arrest caused by hypovolemia?

Tags: heart

Is there a difference between hypovolemic shock and heart arrest caused by hypovolemia ?

Comment: What research have you done? Simply looking up the meaning of these terms would answer the question.

Comment: Please read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. I'm not going to close this question because it has a good answer with upvotes, but future questions without prior research may be closed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hypovolemic shock may be a **reversible cause of cardiac arrest** [(5)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hs_and_Ts)

Mechanisms:

- Acute cardiac ischemia and myocardial infarction: these are due to decreased oxygen supply to the heart itself (remember that shock itself represent global ischemia)(1)[(2)](https://www.uptodate.com/contents/pathophysiology-and-etiology-of-sudden-cardiac-arrest#H1240264379)
- pH changes, especially acidemia: when shock reaches to a irreversible state so much acidosis has developed(1) which itself can cause a cardiac arrest.[(2)](https://www.uptodate.com/contents/pathophysiology-and-etiology-of-sudden-cardiac-arrest#H1240264379)
- Electrolyte abnormalities, most notably hypokalemia, hyperkalemia, and hypomagnesemia: ischemia (untreated) leads infarction leads necrosis leads loss of cell membrane leads ions and enzymes to leak and and produce toxic effects.[(2)](https://www.uptodate.com/contents/pathophysiology-and-etiology-of-sudden-cardiac-arrest#H1240264379) (3)
- Heart Failure:The incidence of sudden cardiac death appears to be increased during periods of worsening HF symptoms.[4](https://www.uptodate.com/contents/pathophysiology-and-etiology-of-sudden-cardiac-arrest/abstract/28).

**While Hypovolemic Shock itself does not involve cardiac arrest,**

- if uncompensated will ultimately cause tissue damage, release of destructive enzymes, acidosis, depletion of cellular ATP. (1)

Pathophysiology:

> As volume status continues to decrease, systolic blood pressure drops. As a result, oxygen delivery to vital organs is unable to meet oxygen demand. Cells switch from aerobic metabolism to anaerobic metabolism, resulting in lactic acidosis.
>
> As sympathetic drive increases, blood flow is diverted from other organs to preserve blood flow to the heart and brain.
>
> This propagates tissue ischemia and worsens lactic acidosis. If not corrected, there will be worsening hemodynamic compromise and, eventually, death.[(4)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK513297/)

**References:**

1. Guyton and Hall Medical Physiology
2. https://www.uptodate.com/contents/pathophysiology-and-etiology-of-sudden-cardiac-arrest#H1240264379
3. Robbins and Cotran Pathologic Basis of Diseases
4. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK513297/
5. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hs_and_Ts